# What number should be on the questionmark?

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

[image]

Please explain your answer below

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Is this a puzzle you created yourself? If not, please provide a link back to the original, otherwise this could be considered plagiarism.